# PHP JasperReports Server API Error

Tags: php, rest, xampp, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am trying to ultimately run and display reports from a remote Jasper Server in a PHP application. What I am trying to do this with is the [jrs-rest-php-client](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-php-client) project on github.

The error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Jaspersoft\Exception\RESTRequestException' with message 'An unexpected HTTP status code was returned by the server' in C:\xampp\htdocs\jrs\vendor\src\Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest.php:409 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\jrs\vendor\src\Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest.php(479): Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest->handleError(0, Array, false) 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\jrs\vendor\src\Jaspersoft\Service\ReportService.php(40): Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest->prepAndSend('https://jasper....', Array, 'GET', NULL, true) 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\jrs\report.php(30): Jaspersoft\Service\ReportService->runReport('/Reports/Distri...', 'html') 
#3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\jrs\vendor\src\Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest.php on line 409
```

My PHP:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
use Jaspersoft\Client\Client;
$d = new Client(
    "http://jasper.server.com/jasperserver-pro",
    "username",
    "password",
    "organization"
);  
$info = $d->serverInfo();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the code of [RESTRequest.php](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-php-client/blob/master/src/Jaspersoft/Tool/RESTRequest.php)  there are two cases in which this exception is thrown:

- A JSON result set with an unknown error code is returned (unknown meaning different from 200 OK)
- No JSON result set is returned at all

So I suspect the connection isn't working properly. To find out more, you should catch the exception in your code and evaluate it:

It could look something like this (I'm more familiar with Java):

```
try {
    $d = new Client(
        "http://jasper.server.com/jasperserver-pro",
        "username",
        "password",
        "organization"
    );  

    $info = $d->serverInfo();

} catch (RESTRequestException $e) {
    echo 'RESTRequestException:';
    echo 'Exception message:   ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    echo 'Set parameters:      ',  $e->parameters, "\n";
    echo 'Expected status code:',  $e->expectedStatusCodes, "\n";
    echo 'Error code:          ',  $e->errorCode, "\n";
}
```

If there is still an error, you can check the following:

- Can you reach the jasper server from the server where this code is deployed? Sometimes e.g. firewall settings can interfere.
- Is the organization called exactly like defined in the properties of the organization in the server? (Open repository / right click on organization / properties / resource-id)