# Create input control using jasper restapiv2

Tags: java, rest, jasperserver

I'm using Jasper API rest v2 https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-java-client. I'm trying to create input control's dynamically.

```
ClientInputControl cliInp = new ClientInputControl();
cliInp.setLabel("FUNCIONARIO_ID_1");
cliInp.setDataType(new ClientDataType().setType(TypeOfDataType.date));
cliInp.setUri("/datatypes/FUNCIONARIO_ID_1");
session.resourcesService().resource("/datatypes").createNew(cliInp);
```

I need to create this input control so I can add to my report.

When executing this code I have

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.exceptions.BadRequestException: Bad Request
```

**EDIT**

Log files give following error:

```
mt error:[{
  "message":"The type 0 is invalid",
  "errorCode":"illegal.parameter.value.error",
  "parameters":
    ["type",
     "0"]
    }]
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should check if you get more information on the error. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871846/php-jasperreports-server-api-error/37161581#37161581) for more infos (it's from the php client but should structurally be similar).

Comment: Hi, in log info , doesn't have more information, only this badrequest.No more detail

Comment: Hi,look better and i found mt error:[{"message":"The type 0 is invalid","errorCode":"illegal.parameter.value.error","parameters":["type","0"]}]

Comment: `TypeOfDataType`, where does this come from? I couldn't find it in the client as well as in the Jasper API, or anywhere else as a matter of fact. Where does this code initially come from, a tutorial?

Comment: from here :  https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-java-client.   this is the java cliente

Comment: Shouldn't I be able then to find `TypeOfDataType`? I cannot find that class and thus cannot look into its `.date` property.

Comment: thanks tobi6. Already solved my problem.

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer for others to see.

Answer (score 1):

You should define more values

```
    ClientDataType type = new ClientDataType()
            .setLabel("Data")
            .setType(TypeOfDataType.date)
            .setUri("/types");

    byte singleValue = 2; 
    ClientInputControl inputControl = new ClientInputControl()              
            .setLabel("Data")
            .setType(singleValue) //this parameter missing is your error
            .setDataType(type)
            .setUri("/inputs");
```